# returns Zeros for Dates that dont exist MYSQL GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, grouping

```
SELECT AVG(data) AS data, dateReg 
FROM table 
GROUP BY YEAR(dateReg), MONTH(dateReg), DAY(dateReg) ORDER BY dateReg
```

the Above Data Returns

```
1.75, 21 Jan 2010
9.45, 22 Jan 2010
3.96, 23 Jan 2010
2.68, 30 Jan 2010
```

Its missing dates from the 24th to 29th, Can we do it so the return value is:

```
1.75, 21 Jan 2010
9.45, 22 Jan 2010
3.96, 23 Jan 2010
0, 24 Jan 2010
0, 25 Jan 2010
0, 26 Jan 2010
0, 27 Jan 2010
0, 28 Jan 2010
0, 28 Jan 2010
2.68, 30 Jan 2010
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typically achieve this type of things by JOIN-ing with a ***value table***, i.e. a table which contains all the values you are interested in.

Typical value tables may contain for example all the integer values between 0 and 1,000,  or all dates for a given period.  Often the Value tables include more values than desired, and we obtain the exact output desired by adding filters in the WHERE clause.

In this case you will require such a table which contain dates.  Assuming this table is named ValTableDates and that it contains all the dates between January 2005 and December 2010, the query would look like:

```
SELECT AVG(data) AS data, VT.ValDate
FROM ValTableDates VT
LEFT JOIN  table T ON T.dateReg = VT.ValDate
WHERE VT.ValDate > [Some Start Date] and VT < [Some End Date]
GROUP BY YEAR(dateReg), MONTH(dateReg), DAY(dateReg) 
ORDER BY dateReg
```

The above query may require a bit of tweaking to get a value Zero rather than NULL, but the main point is that the Value Table is typically the simplest way to provide output records for missing data points.
An alternative is to use a function/expression that produces the desired [date] sequence, inside a subquery, but this is generally less efficient and more error prone.

Comment: Sat for a good 5 minutes trying to word my response that he would need a separate table with date values to join with - your response nailed it :)

Comment: I need to join a table on the right that contains all the dates, Is there no way to do this without generating that table?

Comment: Could i not generate that temp date table using a Query

Comment: Il try posting a function that creates a temp date table and returns that table, However i will add that it might screw with the AVG with 0's that dont join. :(