# Include dates with zero-value in date range

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

[image: My db records]

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t1.eventId,t1.start_date,t1.end_date, COUNT(*) pos FROM events t1
    LEFT JOIN events t2 ON t1.start_date = t2.start_date AND t1.eventId <= t2.eventId
    WHERE t1.start_date BETWEEN  '2012-12-18' AND '2012-12-24'
    GROUP BY t1.eventId,t1.start_date
    ORDER BY t1.start_date,pos ASC
    ) t
WHERE pos <= 3;
```

[image]

WHY start date 2012-12-21 and 2012-12-24  does not exist,

if start_date  does not exist then, i need a null or empty value for

NOTE : no record for 21 and 24.. in my DB but i need a empty value in my Result

Comment: You either need to make an outer join between your table and a table of the dates that you want to appear in the resultset, or else handle missing values in your presentation layer.  I'd recommend the latter unless there's some overriding reason to do this in the database layer?

Comment: There are a fair amount of questions addressing this issue.  Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136480/returns-zeros-for-dates-that-dont-exist-mysql-group-by